# How to add description to DataGridView Cell

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridviewcellstyle

How to add comment to cell in `DataGridView`? I need to comment my values in the grid.

[image: How to add comment to cell in DataGridView? I need to comment my values in grid]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set `ToolTipText` property on either `DataGridViewCell` or `DataGridViewColumn` to whatever text you want.

Answer (score 2):

Each cell can have a tooltip by setting [the `.ToolTipText` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.tooltiptext.aspx) of that cell.  Something like this:

```
// Event for formatting cells when rendering the grid
void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    // Some logic for determining which cell this is in the row
    if ((e.ColumnIndex == this.dataGridView1.Columns["SomeColumn"].Index))
    {
        // Get a reference to the cell
        DataGridViewCell cell = this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];

        // Set the tooltip text
        cell.ToolTipText = "some text";
    }
}
```